# Accessing data within object

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
app.get('/profile/:id', function(req, res){
var options = { method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.favoriot.com/v1/streams?max=1',
    headers: 
    { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'apikey': 'api key' } };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {  
            res.render('profile', {data:body});
    console.log(body)
    });
});
```

when I run code above, I get this data:

> {"debugCode":null,"statusCode":200,"numFound":1,"results":[{"user_id":"xxx510","stream_created_at":"2019-03-05T16:13:01.982Z","stream_developer_id":"f8b8fcb9-6f3e-4138-8c6b-d0a7e8xxxxx@xxxx510","device_developer_id":"raspberryPIxx@xxx510","data":{"distance":"12.4","status":"1"}}]}

how can I make it only display status only?

Comment: There's no middleware used in this code and you can access status from `response.statusCode`

Comment: sorry about that, I'm new in node.js. I try using `response.statusCode` before and I get the response. but the status that I want is inside data: `,"data":"distance":"12.4","status":"1"}}]}`. I try using response.results[0].data.status but i receive error `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: AFAIK there is no issue with the code as such. Are you sure that you got the distance and status in the data field of body or is it the intended output? By try using their (API playground)[https://api.favoriot.com/docs/#!/Data/listStreams] by setting your API key on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no issue with the code as such. Are you sure that you got the distance and status in the data field of body or is it the intended output? By try using their [API playground](http://api.favoriot.com/docs/#!/Data/listStreams) by setting your API key on it. I have rewritten the code using ES6 standards by promisifying request module or you can use the [request-promise-native](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native).

```
function requestPromisified(options) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request(options, function(error, res, body) {
      if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
        resolve(body);
      } else {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}

app.get("/profile/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://api.favoriot.com/v1/streams?max=1",
    headers: {
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "content-type": "application/json",
      apikey: "api key"
    }
  };
  try {
    const body = await requestPromisified(options);
    console.log(body);
    res.render("profile", { data: body });
  } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).send('Unable to find a profile')
  }
});
```

Comment: I manage to solve it. I need to parse it as object first. I add `JSON.parse(body)` and it solve. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

1) There is no middleware in this example... you're just making a call to get some data.

2) `status` is available in `body.results[0].data.status` so just use that instead of the entire `body` object

Comment: sorry about that, I'm new in node.js. i already use that but i got an error :`Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: that usually means results property is not defined for body, you might be encountering an error, so add `if(error) {console.log(error)}` before your `res.render()`